# Spinner click dropdown show status bar

Tags: android, spinner, show-hide

I am using spinner in my applicaltion. In my app Android title bar and notification bar is hidden.
But when i click on the spinner the hidden notification bar is visible for a fraction of a second. Here is my code:

**Main.java:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Hide the Title Bar
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

// Hide the Notification or Status Bar
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.myActivity);
```

**main.xml:**

```
<activity  android:name=".YourClassName"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

}

But still i cant solve this problem.. If anyone has any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tablet resolution then it will not work. 
Try putting

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

in the application like this

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

thanks